# What is the proper way to pronouce EJ?

Tags: pronunciation

I want to make sure that I am pronouncing -*ej*- properly. What is the correct way of pronouncing it?

Answer (score 5):

> **ej** represents **e** plus a short **i**-sound; it is like English *ay* in *play*

Wells, JC, *Esperanto Dictionary*

Comment: Okay. So "EJ" sounds like the word "grey", right?

Comment: Yes, in 'Standard British English'. In IPA it would be like [eI] (see http://www.phon.ucl.ac.uk/home/sampa/english.htm)

Comment: Isn't ⟨e⟩ pronounced short though, more as [ɛ] in the English *bet* /ˈbɛt/? So that would make ⟨ej⟩ [ɛi̯], closer to the Dutch ⟨ij⟩ and ⟨ei⟩ sounds, or the Italian ⟨ei⟩ in [*sei*](http://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/how-do-you-pronounce-the/italian-word-5ef4186b6563f9058e8a96403bc54e534e1520f0.html). I think pronouncing ⟨ej⟩ as [ei̯] is easily confused with ⟨e⟩, as many people (specifically native English speakers) tend to realize ⟨e⟩ as [ei̯] already, hence merging ⟨e⟩ and ⟨ej⟩.

Comment: No, it's the other way round. The [e] is the longer, closed sound. The Dutch "ij" would be [aI]. Also not it's [I] (capital 'i'), which is open and short as opposed to [i]. So _lernejo_ would be [lerneIQ] (using the SAMPA scheme referred to above)

Comment: @OliverMason Uh, sure [e] is long, but that is not usually the sound of ⟨e⟩ in Esperanto. The sound of ⟨e⟩ is the short one: [ɛ] as in *pet*. Moreover, the ⟨i⟩ in Esperanto is [i] (as in *beat*), not [ɪ] (as in *hit*). Finally, I am a native Dutch speaker and ⟨ij⟩ is most certainly not [aɪ̯], but [ɛi̯], or close to [æi̯]. EDIT: Reading the Sampa, the ⟨e⟩ there (exemplified by pet; [ɛ] in IPA) is different from the ⟨e⟩ in ⟨eI⟩ (exemplified by raise; [eɪ̯] in IPA).

Comment: Yes, you're right, I got that wrong.

Comment: @OliverMason Alright, no problem :).

Comment: There is actually a range of acceptable E sounds. Readers of this thread might be interested to read the English and French sections of the Fundamento regarding the correct pronunciation of E in Esperanto.

Answer (score 1):

Lumo5 - I suspect it's not a coincidence that I just made a [video](https://youtu.be/1MFq7nwQmCg) on this very topic where I explain and model the correct way to pronounce -ej-. I had already been working on it when you and I discussed this, and that's why I decided to bump that video up in priority and get it made.

https://youtu.be/1MFq7nwQmCg

To summarize, it's important to pronounce the J in EJ. Otherwise, you won't be able to distinguish *piceo* from *picejo*. Note also that the difference is the J, not the vocal quality. See the video for more details.